# Recursive binary search with default arguments - Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, python-3.x, arguments

I'm trying to write a binary search function in Python that initially takes two arguments from the user: the value being searched for `i` and a sorted array `arr`. Since it won't always be run on the same portion of the array, it also needs two extra parameters, an upper bound `u` and a lower bound `l`; and since I'd like the initial call to only take two arguments, I want to set 0 as the default value for the lower bound (it obviously won't be so in the recursive calls, where `idx` is the lower bound if `idx < i`) and the length of the array as the upper bound (I don't think I need to add 1 since it will always be equal to the highest index plus 1 but correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to pass the length as a parameter. This is my definition:

```
def binSearch(arr, i, l=0, u=len(arr)):
    lower = l
    upper = u
    idx = (lower+upper)//2
    print("Lower bound: " + lower + '\n' + "Upper bound: " + upper + '\n' + "Average: " + idx + '\n')
```

(of course it isn't the actual function, just initial debugging)

And this is the error message I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/programming/python/binarysearch.py", line 1, in <module>
    def binSearch(arr, i, l=0, u=len(arr)):
NameError: name 'arr' is not defined
```

Apparently I can't call a function on an argument name within the arguments, but I can't think of another possible way to translate 'the length of the array I'm going to use' into Python. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default to `None` and if `u` is `None`, set `upper` to `len(arr)`

```
def binSearch(arr, i, l=0, u=None):
    lower = l
    if u is not None: # You could do 'if u' if you're sure u is never 0.
        upper = u
    else:
        upper = len(arr)
    idx = (lower+upper)//2
    print("Lower bound: " + lower + '\n' + "Upper bound: " + upper + '\n' + "Average: " + idx
```

With minor clean-ups:

```
def binSearch(arr, i, lower=0, upper=None):
    if upper is None:
        upper = len(arr)
    idx = (lower+upper)//2
    print("Lower bound: " + lower + '\n' + "Upper bound: " + upper + '\n' + "Average: " + idx
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! (I should also add that I had forgotten to convert the integers to strings but I fixed that).

Comment: @reggaelizard: great to hear that!  and yes converting to strings is necessary, or you could also do `print("Lower bound: {}\nUpper bound: {} \nAverage: {}".format(lower, upper, idx))` to skip the recasting.